# How to get the difference of two string arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to get the exact difference between two string arrays.

```
const array1 = ['T','E','A','P','A','P','E','R'];
const array2 = ['T','A','P'];
```

Expected Output Array:

```
['E','A','P','E','R']
```

I have tried this method:

```
const output = array1.filter(char => array2.includes(char));
```

But that removes all instances of a character, like:

```
['E','E','R']
```

I'm a newbie, so could you guide me to the right direction?

Comment: Whats the result for `["A", "B"] ["B", "A"]` ?

Comment: Should be an empty array.

Comment: Why? Whats the logic behind that?

Comment: I basically have a character array of words (array1). If the user types something in, the character gets added to a used character array. The user is only allowed to type the characters in array1 and if one gets used up, he can't type it in anymore. So I have to have an array with allowed characters, which I use for input control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get difference between two arrays (including duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810641/get-difference-between-two-arrays-including-duplicates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a closure over the index for the second array and increment the index and remove this item from the result set.

```js
var array1 = ['T', 'E', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'P', 'E', 'R'],
    array2 = ['T', 'A', 'P'],
    result = array1.filter((i => v => array2[i] !== v || !++i)(0));

console.log(result);
```

A different approach without a predefined order of `array2`.

```js
var array1 = ['T', 'E', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'P', 'E', 'R'],
    array2 = ['T', 'A', 'P'],
    set2 = new Set(array2)
    result = array1.filter(v => !set2.delete(v));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: According to the (new) specifications of the OP, the order should not matter.

Comment: Thank you very much. That will take some time to digest.

Answer (score 1):

I think filter is not correct apparoch here. Because there are some elements repeadted. Use a simple for-loop. And remove the elements when you add it to result.

```js
const array1 = ['T','E','A','P','A','P','E','R'];
const array2 = ['T','A','P'];
const copy = [...array2];

let res = [];
for(let i = 0;i<array1.length;i++){
  let index = copy.indexOf(array1[i]);
  if(index === -1){
    res.push(array1[i]);
  }
  else copy.splice(index,1);
  

}
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove elements from `allowed` based on the `input` array:

```
 const allowed = ['T','E','A','P','A','P','E','R'];
 const input = ['T','A','P'];

 for(const char of input) {
   const pos = allowed.indexOf(char);
   if(pos === -1) {
     // char doesnt exist?
   } else {
     allowed.splice(pos, 1);
   }
 }
```

Then `allowed` will be your expected result at the end.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to upvote, but lack some points unfortunately.

Comment: @fallc now you can :)